# Can't access BIOS setup. Erased all data on hard drive

Tags: hard-drive, system-restore, compaq-laptop

I was trying to do a factory reset on my HP Compaq laptop, but at the end of the process, it says it is incomplete, and it seems like the hard drive got completely erased.
I can't even access the BIOS setup to set it to boot with the back up that I have on a disk.

How do I fix this? I was running Windows 7 Home Premium 32 bit. I would really appreciate it if you can answer this question for me. Thank you.

Comment: Can you post the exact model of your laptop? This will make it a lot easier for us to answer.

Comment: Computers.. I mean.. desktops and laptops, don't have a 'factory reset' button. Like a pin to push.  Or even AFAIK, a factory reset option in a menu like an android phone.  Furthermore, even if you take the hard disks out it won't affect whether or not you can get into the BIOS, they're independent. HP may have a CD with a restoration method though. But you'd have to get to the BIOS to boot off it. Perhaps you just haven't figured out how. Include some screenshots , take them with your phone. So we see what you see when you try to access the BIOS

Comment: Along with the model number of your HP Compaq laptop, can you tell us what method you are using to access BIOS?

Answer (score 0):

Turn off the computer.

Remove computer from any port replicator or docking station.

Disconnect all external devices connected USB storage devices, external monitors, printers, etc.

Unplug the computer's AC adapter. Remove the battery from the computer compartment.

Hold down the power button for about 15 seconds to fully discharge the capacitors that protect the memory.

Insert the battery and connect the AC adapter to the laptop, but do not connect external devices.

Press the power button to turn the computer on.

If a boot menu appears, use the arrow keys to select Start Windows Normally, and then press Enter. Once all external devices reconnected, run Windows Update and HP Support Assistant to update all device drivers.